# Xamarin: android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView and Inflate not returning correct type

Tags: c#, xamarin, nestedscrollview

I'm working on an Android Xamarin project for which I need to use android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView. I have a view which I am inflating via `LayoutInflator.Inflate` but the type returned is of type `FrameLayout`, not `Android.Support.V4.Widget.NestedScrollView`, which means I can't cast it to the correct type and access the `ScrollView` methods like `SmoothScrollTo`.

The `ToString` of the inflated view is `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView{27428a48 VFED.... .......D 1080,0-2160,1551}` so I know at some level the correct view is being created.

Am I doing something wrong? Could this be a Xamarin bug?

Snippet of view XML as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

..snip..

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

View inflation code:

```
view = (Android.Support.V4.Widget.NestedScrollView)mLayoutInflator.Inflate(Resource.Layout.view_registrationstep2, null);//InvalidCastException
```

Comment: @thumbmunkeys added as requested.

Comment: are you using the layout inflater of the `AppCompatActivity`? Is the shown xml in file `view_registrationstep2.axml`?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys The activity in which this is hosted is derived from `AppCompatActivity`, yes. And yes, the XML pasted is from the layout referenced.